# Решение задачи не проходит

Tags: c++

Есть задача, я её написал, но она не проходит, уверен, что правильно написал. Помогите пожалуйста!

Вот задача

Условие:

> Ксения и Яна отмечают день Святого Валентина. Для подготовки к празднику они составили список из N задач, которые им предстоит сделать. Для выполнения i-той задачи Ксении потребуется X<sub>i</sub> секунд, а Яне потребуется Y<sub>i</sub> секунд.
>
> Для того, чтобы минимизировать время подготовки к празднику, они решили выполнять задачи поочередно. То есть, если Ксения выполняет первую задачу, то после этого Яна выполняет вторую, затем Ксения выполняет третью и так далее.
>
> Порядок изменится, если Яна будет выполнять первую задачу.
>
> Помогите Ксении и Яне найти минимальное возможное время, необходимое для выполнения всех N задач поочередно.

Формат ввода:

Первая строка содержит единственное целое число T – количество тестовых случаев. Далее следует описание тестов в следующем формате:

Первая строка каждого теста содержит единственное целое число N – количество задач.
Вторая строка каждого теста содержит N разделенных пробелами целых чисел, где i-тое число обозначает количество секунд, необходимое Ксении для выполнения i-той задачи.
Третья строка каждого теста содержит N разделенных пробелами целых чисел, где i-тое число обозначает количество секунд, необходимое Яне для выполнения i-той задачи.

Формат вывода:

Для каждого тестового случая выведите в отдельную строку единственное целое число – минимальное возможное время, необходимое для выполнения всех N задач.

Подзадачи:

Подзадача 1: 40 баллов

- 1≤T≤10
- 1≤N≤3
- 1≤X<sub>i</sub>, Y<sub>i</sub>≤10<sup>5</sup>

Подзадача 2: 60 баллов

- 1≤T≤10
- 1≤N≤2*10<sup>4</sup>
- 1≤Xi, Yi≤10<sup>5</sup>

Примеры тестов:

Входные данные:

```
1
3
2 1 2
3 2 1
```

Выходные данные: 5

Мой код :

```
long long t, n, cis, sn = 0, sc = 0;
vector<long long>kseniya;
vector<long long>yana;
cin >> t;

for (long long i = 1; i <= t; i++)
{
    sn = 0;
    sc = 0;
    cin >> n;

    for (long long ii = 1; ii <= n; ii++)
    {
        cin >> cis;
        kseniya.push_back(cis);
    }

    for (long long  ii = 1; ii <= n; ii++)
    {
        cin >> cis;
        yana.push_back(cis);
    }

    for (long long ii = 0; ii < n; ii++)
    {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0)sn += kseniya[ii];
        else sn += yana[ii];
    }

    for (long long ii = 0; ii < n; ii++)
    {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0)sc += yana[ii];
        else sc += kseniya[ii];
    }

    cout << min(sn, sc) << endl;
    kseniya.clear();
    yana.clear();
}
```

Comment: входные данные : 1  3 2 1 2 3 2 1 ответ здесь 5 так как если Ксения начнёт первой ,то будет 6 .

Comment: Никакой пользы от того, что сейчас в заголовке задачи. Думать нужно и о тех, кто после Вас будет заходить в поисках решения проблемы. Название темы нужно изменить.

Comment: То есть вы будете всегда добавлять вектор и условия для каждого человека? Смешно, да и хочется глянуть как вы запоете на сотом человеке =)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку ошибка уже указана, я только добавлю: для указанных входных данных 32-битного `ungigned long` вполне хватает. Кроме того, нет смысла хранить введенные данные. Я бы действовал так:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long subproblem()
{
    unsigned long N, tm, t[2] = {0, 0};
    std::cin >> N;
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> tm; t[i%2] += tm;
    }
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cin >> tm; t[1-i%2] += tm;
    }
    return (t[0] < t[1]) ? t[0] : t[1];
}

int main()
{
    int count;
    std::cin >> count;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        std::cout << subproblem() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `1-i%2` - я бы заменил на более масштабируемое `(i+1)%2`. Вероятно также имеет смысл параметризовать эту двойку внешним циклом.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь ! Я нашёл ошибку

```
    if ((i + 1) % 2 != 0)sn += kseniya[ii];
    else sn += yana[ii];
}
```

здесь нужно ii написать ! Слепой как кот))

Answer (score -1):

Я бы создал функцию int calcolate и в параметрах указать кто делает задачу и собственно время и число операций , и пустить рекурсию. Главное не забыть закинуть в функцию чтобы каждый стек функции менял того кто делает эту задачу. Алгоритм понятен? Реализация уже на ваших плечах

Comment: один только вопрос... "Зачем так сложно?!"

Comment: Мне лично махинации автора совсем не понравились, а как бы сделал ты попроще? Я пока ещё набираюсь знаний и с моей башни просто посмотрел и подкинул алгоритм, а так я хз

Answer (score -1):

у тебя стоят одинаковые условия на суммирование

```
"if((i+1)%2!=0)"
```